# Jade file how to pass a variable for processing

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get a variable from a jade action The code is this

```
form#qeditform(action='/hr/editquestion?qid=SS', method='GET', autocomplete='off', data-ajax='false')
      input#editquestionid(type='hidden', name='editquestionid')
```

But i am not getting anything in result url the result url is like this.

> ditquestion?editquestionid=&editquestionstr=&editsavebtn=Update

Where am i going wrong and how can i fix? I want a value in the generated URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input missing value.

```
input#editquestionid(type='hidden', name='editquestionid', value='somevalue')
```

Comment: My variable is not getting converted into a value  I am using in at this way but in url `input#qid(type='hidden', name='qid',value=qdata[i].questionid.S)` I am getting like this. `http://localhost:8080/hr/editquestion?qid=qdata%5Bi%5D.questionid.S&editquestionstr=dfas&editsavebtn=Update`

Comment: It is a random string like this `ca4abd50-ebd4-11e8-b530-3bcfd2816297`

Comment: `qdata` value not `qid`

Comment: `{"Items":[{"question":{"S":"dsa"},"count":{"S":"0"},"companyid":{"S":"Vowcabs"},"questionid":{"S":"[object Object]"},"userid":{"S":"ravivowcab@mailinator.com"}},{"question":{"S":"FF"},"count":{"S":"0"},"companyid":{"S":"Vowcabs"},"questionid":{"S":"qdata[i].questionid.S"},"userid":{"S":"ravivowcab@mailinator.com"}},{"question":{"S":"dfs"},"count":{"S":"0"},"companyid":{"S":"Vowcabs"},"questionid":{"S":"{\"S\":\"qdata[i].questionid.S\"}"},"userid":{"S":"ravivowcab@mailinator.com"}}],"Count":3,"ScannedCount":3}`

Comment: what's value of `i` in here `value=qdata[i].questionid.S`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183875/discussion-between-arun-vm-and-kibgzr).